# setState when choose a react-router (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I create a web application in the react framework. I am trying to change the state to text when I enter the appropriate router. How can I write it to make it work correctly?

```
class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    title: ""
  };

  render() {
    const { title } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
          {title}
        </Typography>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={HomePage} title="Dashboard" />
          <Route path="/payment" component={FeaturePage} title="Payment" />
          <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't render the `title` inside each route component instead and change it there?

Comment: I don't know how to do it.

Comment: I mean that instead of having the `Typography` component outside of your routing, you could have a separate one in `HomePage`, `FeaturePage` instead.

Comment: @Tholle, `title` it must change in the same file as my routers.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in an update function to your components while still using React router like so.

```
class Header extends React.Component {
state = {
    title: ""
};

updateTitle(newTitle){
    this.setState({title: newTitle})
}

render() {
const { title } = this.state;

return (
  <div>
    <Typography variant="h6" color="inherit" noWrap>
      {title}
    </Typography>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" render={()=> <HomePage updateTitle={this.updateTitle}/>} title="Dashboard" />
      <Route path="/payment" render={()=> <FeaturePage updateTitle={this.updateTitle}/>} title="Payment" />
      <Route path="" component={NotFoundPage} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Uncaught Error: Route(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.

Comment: Sorry about that, my arrow syntax was incorrect and it should be better now.

Comment: This solution doesn't change the state in this class.

Comment: are you calling the updateTitle prop in your child components?

Comment: nope. I don't edit my HomePage and FeaturePage component. What should I write there?

Comment: Sorenson can u help me?